# SharePoint Online Permission to Distribution List - 1 group will be invited, will this send invite?

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, distribution-lists

It's urgent. Highly appreciate quick answers.
I'm using SharePoint Online and now planning to give permission to Distribution List of my organization. While giving the DL name, I see a message like "1 group will be invited". I have unchecked the check box not to send invite. However I see the message there. [image] I don't want to send invitation email for DL. Please clarify, will this send email invite or NOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not send.  I am setting permissions all of the time on SP Online, and always uncheck "Send an email invitation", and it won't send it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Just to clarify particular about DL. You given permission to "Distribution List", and you see that "1 group will be invited" message and still email invite won't send . Am I right?

Comment: Yep, what you're seeing is normal.  It is informing you of what you are inviting.  The "Send an email invitation" check box uncheck means no email invitation will be sent.